# Jquery make a callback function

Tags: jquery, callback

I create a custom script that allows to load html content with ajax (an ajax html content loader).
This script is lunched on element click.

This script works fine with hardcoded element on click.

However, in my html, I append a lots of element thanks to click.

This new appended elements don't success to load content via my ajax html content loader.

I need to callback my ajax script in order to make it work on new appended element.

I don't know how to write my script in order to able a callback.

Here my script :

```
$(function ajax() {
    function ajaxify(file) {
        $.get(file, function (data) {

            var folderContent = $("#bottom-container");
            $("#prev-ajax").fadeOut(0);
            $("#next-ajax").fadeOut(0);
            folderContent.slideToggle(1000,"easeOutCirc", function () {;
            $("#loading-bloc").show();
            $("#loading-text").fadeIn(500);
            $("#ajaxify_container").hide( function () {

            $("#loading-bloc").everyTime(10, function(){                        
            $("#loading-bloc").animate({left:"100%"}, 1000).animate({left:"0%"}, 1000); 
            });
            $("#ajaxify_container").show( function () {         
            folderContent.slideToggle(1000,"easeOutCirc");
            $("#loading-bloc").hide();
            $("#loading-text").fadeOut(500);
            $("#prev-ajax").fadeIn(300);
            $("#next-ajax").fadeIn(300);
           });
        });
    });
    });
}


$('.link:not("#prev-ajax,#next-ajax")').on("click",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var functionAlink = $(this);
    var functionBlink = $(this);

    var $parent= functionAlink.parents('.element'); 

    var prev = $parent.prev().find('.link').attr('href');
    var next = $parent.next().find('.link').attr('href');
    if (typeof prev != 'undefined' ) {
        $("#prev-ajax").attr('href', prev); 
        $("#prev-ajax").animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    }else {
        $("#prev-ajax").removeAttr("href");
        $("#prev-ajax").animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    }
    if (typeof next != 'undefined' ) {
            $("#next-ajax").attr('href', next);
        $("#next-ajax").animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    }else {
        $("#next-ajax").removeAttr("href");
        $("#next-ajax").animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    }   


    var link = functionBlink;
    if (!link.hasClass('current')) {
        $('.link').removeClass('current');
        link.addClass('current');
        ajaxify(link.attr('href'));
        window.location.hash = link.attr("href");
    }

    return false;   
});

$("#prev-ajax,#next-ajax").on("click",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var functionAlink = $(this);
    var functionBlink = $(this);
    //$("#prev-ajax").fadeOut(0);
    //$("#next-ajax").fadeOut(0);


    ajaxify(functionAlink.attr('href'));
    window.location.hash = functionAlink.attr("href");
    $('.link').removeClass('current');


    var href = functionBlink.attr('href');
    var link = $(".link[href*= '" + href + "']:not(#prev-ajax, #next-ajax)");
    link.addClass('current');
    var $parent = link.parents('.element');
    var prev = $parent.prev().find('.link').attr('href');
    var next = $parent.next().find('.link').attr('href');
    if (typeof prev != 'undefined' ) {
        $("#prev-ajax").attr('href', prev);
        $("#prev-ajax").animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    }else {
        $("#prev-ajax").removeAttr("href");
        $("#prev-ajax").animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    }
    if (typeof next != 'undefined' ) {
        $("#next-ajax").attr('href', next);
        $("#next-ajax").animate({opacity: 1}, 300);
    }else {
        $("#next-ajax").removeAttr("href");
        $("#next-ajax").animate({opacity: 0.4}, 300);
    }
});

});



$(function(){
    $(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var hash = location.hash.replace("#","");

if(window.location.hash) {
  $.get(hash, function (data) {
      $('#LoadingImage').show();
            $("#ajaxify_container").fadeOut(1500, function () {
                $(this).html(data).fadeIn(1500, function () {
                    $('#LoadingImage').hide();
                });
            });
        });
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist
}       
  })
  $(window).hashchange();
});
```

Sorry for my English, I'm French

Loïc

Comment: It's hard to know what you're asking, but you are already using the callback in `$.get` to append the elements, so I'm guessing the problem is that the event handlers does'nt work with the dynamic content, and you'll have to use the delegated version of `on()` for that. You can read the jQuery documentation, where it is excellently explained, or search for delegated event handlers on SO.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I already add in my code the `.on` on the click function. This is the click functions that doesn't works on appended elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(quickly read your question, must leave ASAP. Sorry if Off topic) :

Maybe you should try :

```
$(document).on("click",'.link:not("#prev-ajax,#next-ajax")',function (e) {
```

instead of

```
$('.link:not("#prev-ajax,#next-ajax")').on("click",function (e) {
```

Your english is pretty good (from a french point of view ;-)

Comment: You're right!!!! Thanks a lot! It solve all my problems. I need to verify if all click functions works now but it seems to be ok!